# How to read form response URL variables in template?

Tags: form, url

I have a basic login form that's talking to a separate server that's out of my immediate control. I'm trying to read the responses it's sending in the URL within the Craft template.
For example...

```
http://www.adacore.com/login?login=incorrect
```

I've only ever done it before in PHP. Is it possible with Craft/Twig to access these variables directly? Or should I just read the `craft.request.queryString`?

And change the template accordingly as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the built in craft functions.

```
craft.request.getQuery('login')
```

[craft.request documentation here](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request)